# R creating function with For and While

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function in which i can calculate the sum of na's of each column.I tried to use for and while arguments but the result i get is always 0.This is what i tried:

```
sum_na <- function(x){
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    while (i<ncol(x)){
      u=sum(is.na(x[i]))
      return(u)
            i=i+1
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestion to a noob like me would be appreciated!

Comment: `colSums(is.na(x))` Your logic is wrong: the return() is in the loop. The while-loop is obsolete. Eventually you have to use `sum(is.na(x[[i]]))` (depending on what object `x` is)

Comment: `each column` --> use a function of the apply family. Here `apply(dfr, 2, function(x){ sum( is.na(x) ) } )` is what you are looking for in base R.